# Problema ao Fazer JSON a um Site

Tags: php, json

Preciso fazer `JSON` a partir do seguinte link, de forma a obter os dados relativamente a um registro `AWP | Dragon Lore (Field Tested)` do dia: `2017-03-25`.

Link: https://opskins.com/pricelist/730.json

Como poderei fazer um json, de forma a obter o `price`, do seguinte item do seguinte dia?

Pretendo fazer com PHP.

Comment: Poderia melhorar a pergunta? O que você efetivamente precisa? No link que você passou, o resultado já vem em Json.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o index de `AWP | Dragon Lore (Field-Tested)`, contendo uma `-`, caso utilize  (espaço) não irá encontrar, basicamente terá que fazer:

```
$json['AWP | Dragon Lore (Field-Tested)']['2017-03-25']['price'];
```

---

Se quiser menos código faça, *sem cache*:

```
if($resposta = file_get_contents('https://opskins.com/pricelist/730.json')){

    $json = json_decode($resposta, true);
    echo $json['AWP | Dragon Lore (Field-Tested)']['2017-03-25']['price'];

}
```

Se quiser com CURL, *sem cache*:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://opskins.com/pricelist/730.json');

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>1,
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1
]);


if($resposta = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true)){

   echo $resposta['AWP | Dragon Lore (Field-Tested)']['2017-03-25']['price'];

}
```

---

Você pode utilizar um sistema de cache, assim prevenindo ter que baixar todo este conteúdo a todo momento, isso pode poupar recursos do servidor, **por exemplo**:

```
echo getValorDataPorNome('AWP | Dragon Lore (Field-Tested)', '2017-03-25');
```

Retorno:

```
86500
```

Pegando todos os dados:

```
var_dump(getValorDataTodos('2017-03-25'));
```

Retorno:

```
array(8966) {
  ["AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)"]=>
  int(1004)
  ["AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Factory New)"]=>
  int(2829)
  ["AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested)"]=>
  int(1452)
  ["AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Minimal Wear)"]=>
  int(1989)
  ["AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Well-Worn)"]=>
  int(1228)
  ["AK-47 | Black Laminate (Battle-Scarred)"]=>
  int(828)
  ["AK-47 | Black Laminate (Factory New)"]=>
  int(8476)
  ["AK-47 | Black Laminate (Field-Tested)"]=>
  int(758)
  ["AK-47 | Black Laminate (Minimal Wear)"]=>
  int(902)
  ["AK-47 | Black Laminate (Well-Worn)"]=>
  int(827)
//...
```

Utilizando:

```
const CACHE_ARQUIVO = 'json.json';
const CACHE_TEMPO = 120;

function getValorDataPorNome($nome, $data, $json = false){

    $json = $json === false ? getJSON() : $json;

    if(isset($json[$nome][$data]['price'])){

        return $json[$nome][$data]['price'];

    }

    return getValorRecentePorNome($nome, $json);

}

function getValorRecentePorNome($nome, $json = false){

    $json = $json === false ? getJSON() : $json;

    if(isset($json[$nome])) {

        $ultimaData = array_reverse(array_keys($json[$nome]))[0];

        return $json[$nome][$ultimaData]['price'];

    }

    return false;

}

function getValorDataTodos($data, $json = false){

    $json = $json === false ? getJSON() : $json;

    foreach($json as $nome => $item){

        $json[$nome] = getValorDataPorNome($nome, $data, $json);

    }

    return $json;

}

function getJSON(){

    if(existeArquivoRecente() === false && executaCurl() === false){
        die;
    }

    return json_decode(file_get_contents(CACHE_ARQUIVO), true);

}

function existeArquivoRecente(){

    clearstatcache();

    return file_exists(CACHE_ARQUIVO) && filemtime(CACHE_ARQUIVO) > time() - CACHE_TEMPO;

}

function executaCurl(){

    $escreverArquivo = fopen(CACHE_ARQUIVO, "w");

    $curl = curl_init('https://opskins.com/pricelist/730.json');

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS,
        CURLOPT_FILE => $escreverArquivo,
        CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1
    ]);


    if(!curl_exec($curl)){

        return false;

    }else{

        curl_close($curl);
        fclose($escreverArquivo);

        return true;

    }

}
```

> Ele não retorna nenhum exception ou armazena detalhes nos logs, isto não foi adicionado para tentar ser mais simplista. Ele silenciosamente irá obter o último preço, se não houver cadastro daquela data.

Isso irá manter um arquivo em cache por 120 segundos, definido por `CACHE_TEMPO`, ele irá obter o preço (ou retornar `false`, se houver algum erro).

**Funções:**

- `getValorDataPorNome(string $nome, string $data, [array $json]) : string`:

  Obtém o *price* do item na data informada, se houver. Se não houver nenhum preço disponível na data informada irá cair para `getValorRecentePorNome`.
- `getValorRecentePorNome(string $nome, [array $json]) : string`:

  Obtém o *price* mais recente do item informado.
- `getValorDataTodos(string $data, [array $json]) : array`:

  Obtém todos os preços de todos os itens disponíveis, baseado na data informada, se houver, caso não haja um preço diponível na data especificada irá obter o preço mais recente.

---

> Isto foi testado em PHP 7 e PHP 7.1, versões antigas podem ter incompatibilidade, *embora não veja nenhuma evidente*.

Comment: Deu-me o seguinte erro: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42 bytes) in C:\Program Files (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\doente.php on line 4

Comment: Usei o seguinte código: ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

Comment: Já agora, pode dar um exemplo caso eu queira obter os preços dos itens por dia, sem ter que dar o nome do item? Ou seja coloco apenas o dia, e aparece-me o nome dos itens e o respetivo preço.

Comment: A function, está com erro na function: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in C:\Program Files (x86)\VertrigoServ\www\mais.php on line 20

Comment: Qual sua versão do PHP? Se for menor do que o PHP 7, remova o `: bool`, vou editar.

Comment: Agora, está a dar o seguinte erro: Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to getValorItem() must be an instance of string, string given

Comment: Teste isto agora.

Comment: Continua a não funcionar.

Comment: Adicionei que havia falado de pegar todos os dados, experimente desligar o `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`, como está agora, *isto deixar inseguro*.